# How 3mG can be dangerous if the Earth's magnetic field is 500mG?

Tags: electromagnetism, safety, radiation

1. All the things I have read says that magnetic fields above 3milligauss is dangerous for people. How this can be true if the Earth has a magnetic field of 500mG?
2. Do smartphones and gaussmeters measure magnetic fields in a different way? Smartphones always show 500mG which is way beyond human safe limit.

https://www.who.int/peh-emf/about/WhatisEMF/en/index4.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116162/discussion-on-question-by--how-3mg-can-be-dangerous-if-the-earths-magneti).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is all about frequency. The 3 milliGauss limit is referring to high-frequency fields. High-frequency magnetic fields induce electric fields, which cause currents in human tissue. These currents cause heating, which can be dangerous at levels that can be achieved by cell phones and other equipment without proper management and testing. Field limits should depend upon exposure time and frequency.

Static magnetic fields up to tens of thousands of Gauss are not known to have harmful physiological effects, though there are people that worry that they do. Common clinical MRI machines, for example use static fields of 15,000 Gauss and 30,000 Gauss, which is 30,000 and 60,000 times the strength of the Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: smarthone can meassure only static magnetic field?DC power can produce only static magnetic field ,so it is not dangeorous? What type of mag.field meassure gauss meter?

Comment: I don't know what measurement you are referring to that can be performed by a smartphone. DC power can produce any type of field you like, depending upon what you do with that power. Gauss meters can measure both static and ac fields within some bandwidth.

Comment: how  DC power can produce ac magnetic fields?

Comment: You can use the DC power in an infinite variety of ways. A cell phone runs off dc power (the battery), yet it produces ac magnetic fields.

Comment: so ac magnetic  fields above 3mG is not good for human health?

Comment: One cannot make a blanket statement like that. It depends critically on frequency. Most of the legitimate concern that I am aware of begins in the MHz frequency range. There are many studies about exposure to lower-frequency ac fields, but I do not believe there is any scientific consensus that there are harmful effects from fields at very low frequency.

Comment: @rpm2718 Most smartphones have a built in magnetometer commonly used as a compass : essentially for static (DC, or LF as you move around) magnetic fields.

Comment: @Brian Thanks, I forgot about that capability....even though I have used it!

Comment: @rpm2718 what do you think are electric cars dangeorous for human,do they produce ac mag fields?

Comment: I think this discussion is starting to abuse the intended use of the comment section. But to answer your question, no, I don't think ac fields from electric cars are dangerous for humans.

Comment: Tesla Model S can exceed 190mph : that's the real danger.

Comment: @rpm2718 how much is  freqency in electric car?

Comment: I am sorry, but if you have further questions in this area, it would be best to post it as a new question. Comments are not intended for extended discussion.

Comment: @rpm2718 - It's not clear to me in this answer if you are affirming that 3mG is in fact dangerous at certain frequencies. I think we can all agree that there is *some* value that is dangerous, and that it's probably frequency dependent. But is 3mG based on any research, or does it just come from the snake-oil sites?

Comment: @Justin The physiological hazard is heat production, and regulatory limits are not described by field strength, but by power deposition per gram. There are complex geometrical effects to relate local power deposition with field strength, but a few mG starts getting you into the regime where heating effects become a concern in GHz frequency range. This is closely studied by the cell phone industry. It is also a concern in MRI at much lower frequency, but higher rf field strength (hundreds of mG). Heat deposition goes up roughly as the square of the frequency over a broad frequency range.

Answer (score 2):

**3 milligauss *is not* dangerous at *any* frequency.**  Your second link is a known EMF scam company that contains nothing but misinformation intended to get you to buy their snake oil products.  Products that will not have any impact on the electromagnetic fields generated by anything in your home, and they won't create a 'safe space' ***beause your home is already free of danger from EMF***

Websites like these have even forced the Federal Trade Commission to issue [advisories](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0109-cell-phone-radiation-scams) against these scams.  It began with cell phones (and do note that '5G' is featured on the nonsense website), and anywhere that says something along the lines of 'toxic electromagnetic fields' is *definitely*  just the continuation/expansion of this same type of scam.

[Here](https://www.hydro.mb.ca/docs/regulatory_affairs/projects/mmtp/safespace_emf_memo.pdf) is a more in-depth analysis that more formally concludes that nearly everything on that website is nonsense that goes against thousands of peer-reviewed studies and all scientific consensus.  And considering they sell what appears to be a hologram sticker inside a plastic case with metal paint on it for $125, of course it does.

So the simple answer is 3mg isn't dangerous, neither is Earth's magnetic field.  Neither is anything in the chart, which I've gone and updated for accuracy:

[image]

You'd think they would have included fridge magnets, the true scourge of health and safety with their immense 100,000mg worth of magnetic field.  Due to their alternating pole structure, if you rub one down your arm, you can easily achieve an oscillating field of several dozen Hz.

And, let's be clear:  **fridge magnets are not dangerous.**
And neither is anything else on that chart.  Well, at least for reasons relating to EMF.

All the information you need is on your first link, which comes from a much better source:  The World Health Organization

The levels given by the WHO are not even levels above which EMF becomes dangerous:

> It is perfectly safe to eat a pot of strawberry jam up to the expiration date – but if you consume the jam any later the manufacturer cannot guarantee good food quality. Nevertheless, even a few weeks or months after the expiration date, it will usually be safe to eat the jam. Similarly, electromagnetic field guidelines ensure that, within the given exposure limit, no known adverse health effects will occur. A large safety factor is applied to the level known to cause a health consequence. Therefore, even if you experienced field strengths several times higher than the given limit value, your exposure would still be within this safety margin.

Beyond that, the levels given are well above the strength of any fields a person is likely to be exposed to, even if they are near more potent stuff like power lines or an electric rail system.

And even then, they are only potentially dangerous due to localized tissue heating.  This not only requires delivering enough energy to your body, but it must also deliver that energy to a small enough part of your body to cause it to heat up enough to result in internal burns.  Unless you remove the door from your microwave then turn it on or climb to the top of a radio tower so you can put your face directly in the horn opening of the radio transmitter antenna (note: don't do this, it's probably an FCC violation.  Also you might die), this is not something that is going to happen.

**There is one exception however:** If you have a medical implant like a pacemaker, you will want to stay below some recommended level for that device.  This can be as low as 10,000 milligauss for some pacemakers.  Which is still 20 times higher than the EMF from electric trains and trams.

You should avoid arc welders, radar installations, or smelting furnaces and whatever else they tell you to avoid if you have a pacemaker.

I'll conclude this a video of what ***real*** EMF 'exposure' looks like: [(WARNING: Loud)](https://youtu.be/_j2jESz7Zl8?t=98)

It is an electric arc furnace, which is used to melt steel.  The EMF thrown off it actually interferes with the camera's zoom.  Yet, that same EMF continues to harm zero steel workers per day.  Just something to think about.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Funny too! Did you write the Danger column on that chart?

Comment: You are not accounting for the electric field that necessarily comes with a high-frequency magnetic field. It is difficult to find magnetic field strengths typical of cell phones, but I can tell you that in the field of MRI, common rf field strengths are typically 100-500 mG at 64 MHz, and heating (measured as Specific Absorption Rate) is one of the major safety concerns, particularly in the brain. Power deposition increases roughly as the square of frequency over much of the MHz frequency range, so scaling up into the GHz range easily puts you in the few mG level for safety concerns.

Comment: Control of Specific Absorption Rate is a major safety concern in cell phone design, and you will find much written about it if you look.